# Youtube video play error

Tags: android, video, youtube

Following is my source code. I have some youtube video  id's when I try to play these on my android emulator 3.0, some videos are running well after proper loading. But some of the videos takes more time and finally application gets force closed. I am giving here two youtube id's here

1. Ju2Krqv9aDU  (it is running well)
2. IqZf2pj4oj8  (progress dialog takes more time and finally force close)

I have posted here source code  and also error log.

MainLayout.java

```
package com.redorange.motutv;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.redorange.blanklayout_for_initialview.InitialTempFragmentPage;
import com.redorange.dramas.ListOfCategoriesDrama;
import com.redorange.livetv.ListOfCountry;
import com.redorange.motutvstaticdata.MotuTVFunctions;
import com.redorange.motutvstaticdata.MotuTVStaticData;
import com.redorange.movies.ListOfCategoriesMovie;

public class MainLayout extends Activity {

    TextView tvSelectedOptionName;
    TextView tvDate;
    TextView tvUserName;
    Fragment leftLayout;
    Fragment rightLayout;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvDate.setText(MotuTVFunctions.getCurrentDate());

        tvUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
        tvUserName.setText("Hi " + MotuTVStaticData.save_username);

        if (MotuTVStaticData.save_selectedOptionName.equals("Live TV")) {
            leftLayout = new ListOfCountry();
            // rightLayout = new GridViewWeb1();
            rightLayout = new InitialTempFragmentPage();
        } else if (MotuTVStaticData.save_selectedOptionName.equals("Movie")) {
            leftLayout = new ListOfCategoriesMovie();
            // rightLayout = new GridViewWebMovie();
            rightLayout = new InitialTempFragmentPage();
        } else if (MotuTVStaticData.save_selectedOptionName.equals("Drama")) {
            leftLayout = new ListOfCategoriesDrama();
            // rightLayout = new GridViewWebDrama();
            rightLayout = new InitialTempFragmentPage();
        }
        new BackgrndProcessForInitialSettings().execute();
    }

    public void setLeftRightLayout() {
        FragmentTransaction newtransaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();


        newtransaction.replace(R.id.myfragmentleft, leftLayout);
        newtransaction.replace(R.id.myfragmentright, rightLayout);
        newtransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        newtransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    public class BackgrndProcessForInitialSettings extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainLayout.this, "",
                    "please wait...");

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            setLeftRightLayout();
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Error log: 1
[image]

Error log: 2
[image]

Error log: 3

[image]

Comment: Where do you download the videos?

Comment: I am not downloading any videos, i am just getting youtube video id from webservice and trying to play it online from youtube.

Comment: I think you are doing UIThread operation means changing view of UI in a background thread(doInBackground) move it to main thread, like in pre/postExecute or code in runOnUIThread() in that setLeftRightLayout() method.

Comment: The errors you've posted have nothing to do with the question you've asked.  They are "normal" bugs.  Do you have more questions?  Are you trying to solve the NPE, the leak and scroll view multiple child views issues?